# want the background to change every 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k57VE/1/

```
       $(document).ready(function(){

    var images = [ "http://i.imgur.com/X2G0MEL.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/5XMcoCX.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/CTFvvcf.jpg"];
    var currentImage = 0;

function changeBackground() {
    $( '#splash' ).css( { background-image: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')' } );
    if ( currentImage >= images.length - 1 ) {
        currentImage -= images.length;
    }
}

setInterval( changeBackground, 3000 );  
});

});
```

I'm trying to get the background to change every 3 seconds. I have it setup to change the css but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k57VE/3/

Comment: @meagar fair comment, removed

Answer (score 5):

Check your developer console when viewing your own Fiddle link, and you'll find

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

`.css({ background-image: ...` is a syntax error. You need to quote your property name, as literal property names cannot contain hyphens.

```
$('#splash').css({ "background-image": 'url(' + images[++currentImage] + ')' });
```

You also have an extra `})` at the end of your code, which is another syntax error.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle? I changed this but it's still not working.

Comment: Additional to your error above, there were a number of logical problems, your use of ++ and -= was a little weird/confusing. I think this is closer to what you were looking for http://jsfiddle.net/K93aR/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified example of what you're trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/d3YxK/

```
 function changeBackground() {

    if ( currentImage >= images.length ) {
        currentImage = 0;
    }
    $( '#splash' ).css('background-image','url(' + images[ currentImage ] + ')');
    ++currentImage;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `background-image` as identifier. You can make it a string, or use `backgroundImge`:

```
$( '#splash' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')' } );
```

Also, you have a `]);` too much at the end. Also, running the `ready` event from the `load` event is pointless, as the `ready` event happens before the `load` event.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/k57VE/4/